# How to change label text in another viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, swift5

I want to change the text of an label in another viewcontroller.

I have one controller where there is textfields where I can put in text, and a button. 
When I press the button I want the text that is written in the textfields to be replaced with the label text in the other viewcontroller.

I don't want it to go to the other viewcontroller automaticly, just press the button and it's done. Then I can navigate to the other viewcontroller myself inside the app and the text should be changed.

I'm also comepletely new to this, just to clarify.

Comment: When you have data sharing between view controllers, especially ones that aren't immediately connected to each other, it's often better to move it out of the controllers.  For example, you could have one of them write to `UserDefaults` and the other read from there when it needed the info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a global solution. İf i were you i try to declare my all variables global.
For example think one variable as global named a_global

When you tap button go and change global variable to what u want

If you go to "changed label text" viewcontroller set the label.text = a_global